# My 2d array is not functioning in my do while loop

Tags: c

When I make an array like: `array[tshelf][tslot] = item;` There is an error 
when running the code. Any idea why? I believe that I did it correctly, but it does this weird thing when I run it.

```
typedef struct shelfitem {
    char str[75];
    int price;
} shelfitem;
int main() {
    int a;
    int s;

    printf("How many shelves are in the unit?\n ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("How many slots are available on each shelf to hold items?\n");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    shelfitem array[a][s];
    int tshelf;
    int tslot;
    char tempname[75];
    int tempprice;
    char q[75];
    int tcoord;
    int tcoord2;

    printf("You have created a shelving unit \n");

    do {
        printf("Please add a new item to the shelve by giving <name>,<price>,<shelf>,<slot> or type 'quit' when finished\n");
        scanf("%s, %d, %d, %d", tempname, &tempprice, &tshelf, &tslot);
        shelfitem item = {
                *tempname, tempprice
        };
      array[tshelf][tslot] = item; //THIS LINE IS THE ERROR
    } while (strcmp(tempname, "quit") != 0);
```

The output is weird.

Comment: What kind of error?

Comment: it lets me type in something. then does an enter space. then exits

Answer (score 1):

`scanf()` is not a pattern matching function. `%s` will process everything up to the next whitespace character; writing `%s,` will not make it stop before the comma. To make it not include the comma in the name, you need to use `%[^,]` instead of `%s`. And then you need to put a space before it, so it will skip over whitespace before processing an input.

Another problem is that you can't copy strings using simple assignment; `*tempname` just refers to the first character of the array. You need to use `strcpy()`.

You should check for the "quit" input BEFORE you add to the array, otherwise you'll create an item whose name is `quit`. Instead of a `do-while` loop, use `while (1)` and then use `break` to stop the loop when the user enters "quit".

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct shelfitem {
    char str[75];
    int price;
} shelfitem;

int main() {
    int a;
    int s;

    printf("How many shelves are in the unit?\n ");
    scanf("%d", &a);
    printf("How many slots are available on each shelf to hold items?\n");
    scanf("%d", &s);

    shelfitem array[a][s];
    int tshelf;
    int tslot;
    char tempname[75];
    int tempprice;

    printf("You have created a shelving unit \n");

    while (1) {
        printf("Please add a new item to the shelve by giving <name>,<price>,<shelf>,<slot> or type 'quit' when finished\n");
        scanf(" %[^,], %d, %d, %d", tempname, &tempprice, &tshelf, &tslot);
        if (strcmp(tempname, "quit") != 0) {
            break;
        }
        strcpy(array[tshelf][tslot].str, tempname);
        array[tshelf][tslot].price = tempprice;
    }
}
```

Note that because of the way you're using `scanf()`, they have to enter something like `quit,1,2,3`. It would be better to use `fgets()` to read a whole line, test for `quit`, then call `sscanf()` to parse the line.

Comment: You should check for the "quit" input BEFORE you add to the array, good catch.

Answer (score 0):

```
    shelfitem item = {
            *tempname, tempprice
    };
```

You are assigning not the address of the first character of `tempname` to `str`, but the first character itself. This is incorrect and the compiler should give an error.

The second problem is that the C compiler does memberwise assignment (shallow copy). This is not what you need. What you need is a deep copy:

```
void cpyShelf(shelf *dest, shelf *src)
{
    assert(dest && src); /* enforce precond.: dest and src are non-null */

    strcpy(dest->str, src->str);
    dest->price = src->price;
}
```

In addition, your code is susceptible to a stack overflow if `a` or `s` is too large and a buffer overflow if the user inputs more than 74 characters for `tempname`. Also your variable `q` is unused.

Comment: thanks, but I am pretty beginner at c programming. The second correction, what do you mean? Like.. in baby terms

Comment: @educationalmonkey97 Do a Google search of the terms I mentioned: memberwise assignment, shallow copy and deep copy